# Asus e203ma several keys on the keyboard do not work

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, laptop, asus, mint

I have an Asus e203ma laptop (4GB RAM, 32GB ssd). It was running Windows 10 from the factory, but it was taking up most of its capacity (only 500MB are free), so I decided to install Windows 10 LTSB Compact. Everything was fine, but after some time it stopped working some keys (s, c, b, spacebar, etc.). In Device Manager, the keyboard had drivers for 105 keys, but it only has 82 (+ 1 shutdown key). I was not able to change this on Windows, so I installed Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon. Everything worked on the live system, everything worked on the installed system, but the next day those same "problem" keys stopped working. After a day of manipulation I broke the system, wi-fi stopped working. I tried to test the keyboard in the live Mint system, but this time the keys also did not work! I tried the Ubuntu 22.04 live system and the keys did not work either. On both systems, running `sudo debconf-show keyboard-configuration` showed the keyboard type with 105 keys. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 to change this configuration with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`. The Asus laptop configuration did not change anything, nor did the configuration for the 86-key keyboard. The configuration where no model assignment occurs helped. But! The keys still don't work correctly, they may not be pressed, after holding for a long time they "snap off" and work with a delay, and then later turn off again. At the same time Ctrl does not work. Using `showkey` I see the codes of the "working" keys, but the "problem" keys although they appear half the time do not create their own code output (for example, they go 30, 32, 33, where 32 is not displayed for "s"). In UEFI all the keys with letters and arrows work, I checked in the field to create a password. The USB keyboard (the big one, with the numpad) and the small bluetooth keyboard also work. For Windows I tried installing the drivers from Asus, there were several versions, but none of them worked for me. I settled on the linux option, as I believe it is the one that will allow me to prescribe a working config for my keyboard, even completely with my own hands. I would be very grateful for any help, as I have wasted a week already and cannot use my laptop

Comment: You appear to be describing a hardware issue, which is best resolved via change/replacement of keyboard.  This is a Ubuntu Q&A site, so why ask here about what you describe as a hardware issue (*hardware is off-topic like windows & Linux Mint* - refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @guiverc Thank you for your attention to my question! The problem is not hardware, because the keyboard works fine in the BIOS. And also, when I change the keyboard configuration in the system, its behavior changes, where the "problematic" keys sometimes work, albeit badly. Also, everything worked fine on Windows 10 (but I can't use it because it takes up all the space). The problem is in the operating system